# Copying the location of file names with specific extensions

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code for listing all files in a folder and sub folder with path.

I want to list files which have specific extensions (for example: .txt files alone).

How can I do this?

My code so far:

```
Sub Test()

Call ListFilesInFolder("D:\Downloads", True)

End Sub


Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal SourceFolderName As String, ByVal IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim r As Long
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)
r = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    Cells(r, 1).Formula = FileItem.Name
    Cells(r, 2).Formula = FileItem.Path
    r = r + 1 ' next row number
    X = SourceFolder.Path
Next FileItem

If IncludeSubfolders Then
    For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
        ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
    Next SubFolder
End If

Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you have tried?

Comment: Creating a list of sub folders and their contents is possible with the operating system, which python could call directly - see http://superuser.com/a/319009

Comment: You might want to use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetExtensionName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0fxha2a(v=vs.84).aspx) like this:

```
Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal SourceFolderName As String, ByVal IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim r As Long
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)
r = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
  If FSO.GetExtensionName(FileItem) = "txt" Then 'change txt as you want
    Cells(r, 1).Formula = FileItem.Name
    Cells(r, 2).Formula = FileItem.Path
    r = r + 1 ' next row number
  End If
  X = SourceFolder.Path
Next FileItem

If IncludeSubfolders Then
For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
Next SubFolder
End If

Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```